# Will taking a paycut impact my future salary negotiations and expectations?

Tags: salary, academia, pharma-industry

I am a scientist in the pharmaceutical industry and trying to transition into a slightly different role that requires a skillset that I do not have. I am considering taking a postdoctoral position to get the training I need, but it will require a massive pay cut (~60% lower salary) for the duration of the postdoc(1-2 years).

My question is, once I finish my postdoc, can I still negotiate salary based on my industry job? Or will my salary start from the ground floor again because of how little I made during the postdoc?

Comment: Good question, I would think not if you made it clear it was a postdoctoral position, they're a specific case scenario rather than a normal job position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I still negotiate salary based on my industry job? Or will my salary start from the ground floor again because of how little I made during the postdoc?

Neither. You negotiate your salary based on what the "market rate" for the specific job is and how you stack up against other candidates.

Comment: While this is true for many countries, I have seen enough questions here that required "the last pay slip" in their interview. Something that would certainly make me walk out of the door where I live, but apparently it's a thing in other parts of the world. So I don't know if it should be such a blanket statement.

Comment: @nvoigt this is exactly what I'm trying to figure out here in the United States. Salary negotiations often involve assessing current lifestyle needs (as ridiculous as it sounds) and trying to get away with paying you slightly more than your current salary. What I wish to know is whether I can leverage lifetime salaries or have to start from base.

Comment: You don’t have to provide a pay stub to get a job in the United States that’s something you can refuse to provide

Comment: As an additional note, postdocs in the US are pretty much set at 40-60k annual salary so any hiring manager will know your current salary range.